# In datatable more than 10 records show pagination otherwise not display pagination using datatables

Tags: datatables

In My website I am using data tables for display data. Now The issue is If there are 10 records than the default pagination is not display but when there are more than 10 records the pagination of data table should display.

This is how I initialize datatable

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tbl_member').dataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {"bSortable": true, "aTargets": [0,2]}
            ]
        });
});
```

This datatable code is when I done server side processing:-

```js
var save_method; 
var table;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      table = $('#table').DataTable({ 
        oLanguage: {
        sProcessing: "<img src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/loader.gif'>"
        },
        "processing": true, 
        "serverSide": true,     
        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url();?>Technology/technology_list",
            "type": "POST"
        },

       "columnDefs": [
        { 
          "targets": [ -1 ], 
          "orderable": false, 
        },
        ],
      });
    });
```

Comment: How do you intialise the dataTable? Ny markup, by AJAX, by JSON ...? Please show some code ....

Comment: I also Done server side processing in datatable. For that I paste some code of datatable. If I apply below answer It's not working in that

Comment: That is exactly why I asked :) There are different approaches to different situations. So, `Technology/technology_list` will return a JSON? If I knew more I would happily create an example : Listen for the `xhr` event, disable `#table_filter` and `#table_length` if records<10, would love to produce an example but need to know how the AJAX response is formed.

Comment: Yes Technology/technology_list will return a JSON. I paste technology_list method code.

Comment: But How I solve that more than 10 records issue in this datatable code

Comment: See updated answer, hope it helps. When you have wellformed "datatables-ready" JSON as in your case it is easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `bPaginate` (old hungarian notation style) or `paginate` to turn pagination on or off. You can use expressions to determine the options :

```js
$('#tbl_member').dataTable({
   "bPaginate" : $('#tbl_member tbody tr').length>10,
   "iDisplayLength": 10,
   "bAutoWidth": false,
   "aoColumnDefs": [
       {"bSortable": true, "aTargets": [0,2]}
   ]
});
```

This works in both 1.9.x and 1.10.x versions of dataTables. Demo showing two tables with the one having less than 10 records, the other a lot more -> **http://jsfiddle.net/t2xcfLap/3/**

---

Hide pagination controls after an AJAX update. Assuming the JSON reponse  is on the form

```js
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 3,
  "recordsFiltered": 3,
  "data": [
    [...],
  ]
}
```

then

```js
table.on('xhr', function(e, settings, json, xhr) {
    if (json.recordsTotal<10) {
        $("#example_paginate").hide();
        $("#example_length").hide();
    } else {
        $("#example_paginate").show();
        $("#example_length").show();
    }        
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/yyo5231z/**

The injected controls is named on the form `<tableId>_length`, `<tableId>_paginate`. So if your table have the `id` `table`, then the above should be `$("#table_paginate").hide();` and so on.

The reason for the different approach compared to the first answer with a static table is, that you cannot change pagination on the fly without re-initialising the table.